# How do I use image for nav background in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I use Bootstrap 4 with a pattern background

Just converting website to use Boostrap and currently I have this header using the dark background and it looks fine but ideally instead of just the dark grey background I want to use the patterned background I was previously using as the nav bar, this would go over the whole width of the page instead of the dark grey.

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark container text-center">

        <a href="http://jthink.net/index.jsp" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="http://www.jthink.net/images/icon32.png"  width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            JThink
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://blog.jthink.net">
                    Blog
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/jaikozforum">
                    User Forum
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/songkong">
                    SongKong
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/jaikoz">
                    Jaikoz
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://albunack.net" target="_blank">
                    Albunack
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp" >
                   Jaudiotagger
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

e.g instead of looking like this

[image]
I want the blue background in this screenshot to be used for the navbar

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `.navbar { background-image: url("[file-name].png"); }`? If it's inside your app's directory, don't forget to include the route, for example; `/assets/images/file.png`.

Comment: No with Boostrap4 Im trying very much to do things the right way rather than just guessing, so is that the right way ?

Comment: That is how you link to files to use as a background image. It's not bootstrap specific, it is a regular CSS property. Try it out, let me know if it works and I can make it an answer.

Comment: ok, removing bg-dark from outer div and nav-bar and then adding  style="background-image: url(http://jthink.net/songkong/images/songkongheader.png);" to outer div worked.

Comment: Trouble is make the hyperlink text harder to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a background image to your bootstrap navbar by adding a `background-image` style to the div surrounding your `navbar`.

Here are the attributes you can apply to your image:

```
background-image: url("[file-location].png");
background-repeat: ;/* Determine what direction the image will repeat */
background-position: ; /* Where the image will be positioned relative to "top, right, bottom, and/or left */
background-attachment: ; /* use with "fixed" to make it scroll with page */
```

Read more about this property at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

If the background image is making your hyperlink hard to read, change its normal color using `color: [hex value / color name];` on `nav-item` or `nav-link` like this:

```
.nav-item > a {
  color: #000000; /* [hex value / color name] */
}
```

Then you can change the color of the link when you hover over it by using the following:

```
.nav-item > a:hover {
  color: red; /* [hex value / color name] */
}
```